# Toggle image src on click

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Hi angular community !

I've got an img who's also a button an I would like to change the button/img as following "each time it's clicked show img "arrow_up" , maybe ngClass changing the css?

My button is an arrow down and each time he is clicked I would like it show an arrow up instead like in this website for exemple [Angular Blogspot](http://angularjs.blogspot.fr/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html) (if you see the blog archive on right, if you click on it the boutton changed..very common thing)

I provide an exemple with [hidden] but maybe there's a elegantest way to do the job:

html:

```
<img src="./arrow_down_black.png" type="button"
(click)="toggleChild()"/>
<img [hidden]=""showVar" src="./arrow_up_black.png" type="button"(click)="toggleChild()"/>
   <my-child [showMePartially]="showVar"></my-child>
```

ts:

```
clickMe() {
   this.showVar = !this.showVar;
}
```

Comment: you description is not clear. What do you actually want to achieve ?

Comment: @Faisal hi Faisal since this morning ! My button is an arrow down and each time he is clicked I would like it show an arrow up instead like in this website for exemple http://angularjs.blogspot.fr/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html (if you see the blog archive on right, if you click on it the boutton changed..very common thing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an expression to display the correct image.

```
<img src="{{ showVar ? './arrow_down_black.png' : './arrow_up_black.png'}}" 
     type="button" (click)="toggleChild()"/>

     <my-child [showMePartially]="showVar"></my-child>
```

.. and in your component ts file,

```
toggleChild() {
   this.showVar = !this.showVar;
}
```

Comment: many thanks it works fine .. do you know some tutorial where i could learn how to use this typescript expression? I understand ? = if and : = or but didn't find explantations about it..

Answer (score 2):

I think  binding  your img css class to the [ngClass] directive will do the job more elegant way.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'active': isActive, 'disabled': isDisabled}">
```

[NgClass directive example](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Comment: according to my code in the post, how could you make...I didn't get it..

Comment: @EmileCantero it will look something like that `<img [ngClass]="{'name of css class arrrow up img': showVar, 'name of css class arrrow down img': !showVar}" type="button"(click)="toggleChild()"/>`

Comment: Thanks guys both solutions are working solutions I need to learn more to do disturb you to much